# Existence and uniqueness for a PDE by classical semigroup theory

Tags: partial-differential-equations, semigroup-of-operators

I am currently reading the following paper:

Chen, X. The Hele-Shaw problem and area-preserving curve-shortening motions. Arch. Rational Mech. Anal. 123, 117–151 (1993). https://doi.org/10.1007/BF00695274

But I am stuck with the following step:

We want to prove existence and uniqueness for this PDE
\begin{equation}
f_{t} + \varepsilon J^{-4}(t,x) f_{xxxx} = F(t,x) 
\end{equation}
Chen then approximates $ \frac{1}{2} \leqq J \leqq 2$ and $\vert F(t,x) \vert_{L^{2} (S^1 \times (0,T))}^2 \leqq C \varepsilon^2 (E_0 T + M)$, where $0<E_0 < \infty $ and $T,M>0$ can be made as small as needed. From these inequalities he then concludes that the PDE admits a unique solution in $L^2[0,T;H^4(S^1)] \cap H^1[0,T;L^2(S^1)]$ by classical semigroup.

I am not so familiar with semigroup theory, but I know that in the homogenous case the statement is true by virtue of the Hille-Yosida Theorem for unbounded operators. However I am not familiar with a general proof for inhomogeneous PDEs.

My question, therefore, is how one can prove the existence in this case. Is there a theorem for this? What is the technique to use?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm studying semigroups now. I haven't get to this part yet, but what I've seen so far is that if $A$ is the infinitesimal generator of a $C_0$-semigroup ${S(t)}$ on a Banach space $V$ and $F\in C^1([0,T];V)$ then the solution for $u'(t)=Au(t)+f(t)$ is $v(t)=\int_0^tS(t-s)f(s)\, ds$. I see this in the book of Kesavan "Topics in Functional Analysis and Applications"